# Login item Helper app not opening the main app cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos

In my mac app when i am trying to set run at startup getting message in console `com.companyname.myhelperapp[14002]: registration request failed: (0x10, 0x3) The code signature is not valid: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -2147409652.)`
 this was working fine from more than a year but getting this wierd issue .

Any Suggestions ?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Update certificates.

Comment: @ElTomato can you explain in detail how to do.